# Check if there is invalid data in a sheet?

Tags: vba, validation

How can I know with VBA if there if there are validations errors in a sheet? I've been looking into the range.validation object but I didn't find any methods or properties to do this.

Comment: Would the validation not disallow the entry?

Comment: Would help to expand your question with some concrete examples of what you want to check for.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - I believe you bypass the validation process by programatically setting values to a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like.  F9 has validation of any number between 1 and 10

```
Option Explicit

Sub t()

Range("f9").Value = 100

Dim r As Excel.Range

Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)

Dim c As Excel.Range

For Each c In r.Cells

    If Not c.Validation.Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Address & " is not validated"
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```